# My Output repeats by one time on clicking the button

Tags: html, jquery

Can you find out the problem in this code ? My output gets repeating one time on clicking on submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var arr=[];
    var text="";
    $("#txtResult").click(function()
    {
        var string = $("#txtFirstNo").val();
        arr.push(string);
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
             text += arr[i] + "<br>";
        }
        $("p").html(text) ;
    }
  )
 
})
    </script>
```

Comment: can you put the relevant html and expected and actual output in the post

Comment: This is happening because you `push()` a new item in to the array on every iteration, then you display that full array appended to all previous `text`. Without knowing what output you expect, we can't really help you accurately.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have `var text="";` outside your click. So that never gets reset

Comment: Or just remove the whole `arr` code and use the one-liner `$("p").append( $("#txtFirstNo").val() + "<br/>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are appending array values to `text` variable which is declared and initialized outside click event handler.
You need to re-initialize `text` variable before for loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var arr=[];
    var text="";
    $("#txtResult").click(function()
    {
        text=""; // re-initialize 
        var string = $("#txtFirstNo").val();
        arr.push(string);
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
             text += arr[i] + "<br>";
        }
        $("p").html(text) ;
    }
  )
 
})
    </script>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)